# Proof of trig identity involving $\cos^4 (x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need help regarding the proof of a trig identity without operating across the equals sign. Here's the original identity:

$$\cos^4(x)+2\cos^2(x)-\sin^4(x)=2\cos(2x)+1$$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \cos^4{x}-\sin^4{x} = (\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x})(\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}) = \cos{2x} \cdot 1, $$
and
$$ 2\cos^2{x} = \cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}+1 = \cos{2x}+1. $$
Add.

---

Note also that proving that $A-B=0$ is the same as proving $A=B$, so if you prefer you can start with the difference of both sides and show that it is zero, which allows you to work with both sides of the original in a logically sensible way.